# find $E( \sin (X) )$ by two ways, where $X$ uniformly distributed $[0,\pi]$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables, expected-value

let $X$ be uniformly distributed on $[0,\pi]$

find $E(\sin(X))$ using **Proposition 2.1,** and then check the result by using the definition of expectation.

> Proposition 2.1
>   If $X$ is a continuous random variable with probability density function
>   $f (x)$, then, for any real-valued function $g$,

[image]

my solution using  Proposition 2.1
$c=1/\pi$
$E(sin(x)) = integration ( 1 / \pi sin(x) dx ) = 2 / \pi $

how can I check result by results by using the definition of expectation ??

Comment: 2.1 does not hold for all real valued functions, but only for Borel functions. However, you can and should use it in this instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
\mathsf{E}\sin(X)=\int_0^\pi\frac{\sin(x)}{\pi}\,dx=\frac{2}{\pi}.
$$

Comment: But according to the formula above, $E[\sin(X)] = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x \cdot \sin(x) dx = \int_{0}^{\pi} x \cdot \sin(x) dx = \pi$.

Comment: I need to approve it but 2ways according to the formula and by definition of expectation

Comment: how can I check result by results by using the definition of expectation ??

Comment: @predactor What is your definition of expectations?